# How to find magic bytes for the .pyc header in Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to find magic bytes for Python version 3.7
I've tried here:
https://shankaraman.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-fix-runtimeerror-bad-magic-number-in-pyc-file/
and here:
https://programmer.group/record-the-decompilation-process-of-python-3.7-once.html#3magic_number_63
and also google it, but no luck so far, so

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [constant for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html?highlight=magic%20number#importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER) in the standard library: `importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER` represents the bytes for the `.pyc` magic number for the current Python interpreter.

Comment: Lightning fast ⚡